# Extending private methods of a ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, extending

Say that I've a Component that is being passed as a Child to another Component.

I know it's probably not a best practice, but how would you extend some internal methods of the child in the parent? I'm not talking about props, I'm talking about the very private methods you define in a React Class.

I tried playing with an higher-order component, `Component.prototype` and `Component.prototype.__reactAutoBindMap` but I got unexpected results.

I'm wondering if 1) is this possible and 2) is there a proper way to handle this case

**UPDATE**

Here's a fiddle demonstrating the use case https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/11257/ (open the console and look for 'trackEvent')
I realized that were something wrong with my previous Coffee-script code.

Comment: Do you have access to the component code? You can set hooks in the component methods to activate methods passed from the parent as props

Comment: I suppose you could extend the component using [regular prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript#Inheritance). But as you suggested, it's a bad practice so there's not really a "proper" way to do it.

Comment: Crazy, I put up a jsfiddle in Javascript + JSX and it works like expected https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/11254/ so now I'm wondering that as I was using Coffeescript + CJSX on my previous tests, probably something is messed up. pffff